# firefox not showing whole sprite image

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have created one sprite image which size is 100x12000 pixels and created one web application which use this image icons with proper poistion. It works in Chrome, opera and IE but in Firefox 35 it shows only half icons of image other part of image shows blank. what will be the problem? like given image
[image]

Thanks.
Sandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is very long, this is a known problem in Firefox. The most the program can handle with hardware acceleration disabled is a height or width up to 32,766 pixels. You can get more of the painful details in this thread: ["This image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/960717).

Comment: okay got it, my image size is 100 * 12000 pixels, it is showing up to 32,766 pixels after that the image getting blank.