# Firefox won't load images full in background div

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

we have a strange problem with firefox on this site: 
http://golfpark-rothenburg.de

The Images in the background won't load full. Sometimes only a little bit of the image is missing and sometimes more. 
And it only appears on firefox (mac and win).

I realized that with a fixed div:

```
<div id="mainimg">

<div class="custom"  >
<p><img src="/images/background/hintergrundnebenmenue2.jpg"   alt="hintergrundnebenmenue2" /></p></div>

</div>
```

Here the css of the images div:

```
#mainimg {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mainimg img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#mainimg p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

And I resize this image with onload and on resize:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
            if(jQuery(window).width() > jQuery(window).height()) {
                if((jQuery(window).width()*(1500/2000)) < jQuery(window).height()) {
                    jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "height", jQuery(window).height() );
                    jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "width", jQuery(window).height()*(2000/1500) );
                } else {
                    jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "height", jQuery(window).width()*(1500/2000) );
                    jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "width", jQuery(window).width() );
                }
            } else {
                jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "height", jQuery(window).height() );
                jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "width", jQuery(window).height()*(2000/1500) );
            }




        }); 

        jQuery(window).resize(function(){
            if(jQuery(window).width() > jQuery(window).height()) {
                if((jQuery(window).width()*(1500/2000)) < jQuery(window).height()) {
                    jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "height", jQuery(window).height() );
                    jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "width", jQuery(window).height()*(2000/1500) );
                } else {
                    jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "height", jQuery(window).width()*(1500/2000) );
                    jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "width", jQuery(window).width() );
                }
            } else {
                jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "height", jQuery(window).height() );
                jQuery("#mainimg img").css( "width", jQuery(window).height()*(2000/1500) );
            }           





        });
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: I suggest that you use CSS3 background-size property to fill the background image instead of jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [firefox not showing whole sprite image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981487/firefox-not-showing-whole-sprite-image)

Comment: @ Salman A This isn't a possibility at the moment, because the customer inserts this images for each page and he can't insert it as background

@ Pinal I don't think that this is the problem - because the images i use aren't that big